# How we can achieve the Hierarchy in Outlook Address Book

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

[We want to achieve something like this in Outlook Address Book dialog Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvqfo.png)

How we can achieve the hierarchy in Outlook Address Book dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Your containers must have `PR_DEPTH` property exposed.

Comment: We are using the Address Book provider from Microsoft's CONTAB32.DLL OpenEntry function.
By using this we are able to Open the Contabs diffrent folder like "Global Address List" and custom folders etc.

So i have the below code where it is opening the contab root folder and sub folders. In below code i am able to retrive the PR_DEPTH property but cant set it back with my custom value.

Can you pin-point what is the issue in below code or Do you have any sample code how this can be done?

Comment: Zimbra::Util::ScopedInterface<IABContainer> lpRootCont;
    HRESULT hResult = lpAddrBook->OpenEntry(0, NULL, NULL, 0, &ulObjType,
        (LPUNKNOWN *)lpRootCont.getptr());
    Zimbra::Util::ScopedInterface<IMAPITable> lpRootHier;
    lpRootCont->GetHierarchyTable(fMapiUnicode | CONVENIENT_DEPTH, (LPMAPITABLE *)lpRootHier.getref());
    hResult = lpRootHier->SetColumns((LPSPropTagArray) & tagsContabHier, 0);
    hResult = lpRootHier->QueryRows(1, 0, pContabEntry.getptr());
    while (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && 0 != pContabEntry->cRows)
    {

Comment: while (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && 0 != pContabEntry->cRows)
    {
        LPSPropValue lpEntryProps = pContabEntry->aRow[0].lpProps;
    SPropValue prop;
    prop.ulPropTag = PR_DEPTH;
    prop.Value.l = 2; // Set the PR_DEPTH property
    hResult = HrSetOneProp(spContainer.get(), &prop);